# Android Studio засунуть сайт в приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет, подскажите как засунуть сайт в приложение ? к примеру как тут http://www.appsgeyser.com/create-url-app/ где об этом почитать можно ? или пример, курс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду отображение какого-то сайта в вашем приложении, то для этого есть элемент WebView

1) В разметке добавляете:

```
<WebView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/web_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

2) В коде для загрузки требуемого сайта используете следующее:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.loadUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
```